# i want to add $ in front of numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here I’m trying to add 0.05 whenever the button was clicked, and it is perfectly working.

```
price = [uPaidTxtFld.text floatValue];
result=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", price+0.05];
[uPaidTxtFld setText:result];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:result forKey:@"price"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

OUTPUT:

```
0.05, 0.10, 0.15, ….
```

But i want output $0.05 whenever the button was clicked the amount must be added and before the amount must be a dollar symbol.  This one i tried but not working….

```
NSString *dollarSymbol = @"$";
price = [uPaidTxtFld.text floatValue];
result=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%.02f",dollarSymbol, price+0.05];
[uPaidTxtFld setText:result];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:result forKey:@"price"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

OUTPUT:

```
$0.05, $0.05, $0.05, …
```

Whenever i clicked the button it will show only $0.05, i.e, not adding …

Comment: Why don't you just use a separate variable to store the accumulating price amount rather than getting it from the text field text value? I don't think you can convert "$0.05" and expect "floatValue" to return 0.05, it's probably returning 0.0 everytime instead.

Comment: because i want both dollar symbol and amount in center.  in case the amount is above the 100.00 then i want to adjust the dollar symbol.  Each and every time i want to adjust the dollar variable about amount (two and three digits)

Comment: This is not a pretty solution, because it breaks several important rules (mixes up formatting and representation, and uses `float` to represent currency, to name a few). iOS provides superb facilities for working with currency. If you want to write good programs, learn about `NSDecimalNumber` and `NSNumberFormatter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to do it that way, you can just grab the number from the string by excluding the first character. However, I agree with the first commenter and recommend storing the number in a separate variable. That would probably be a cleaner way to do it.

```
NSString *dollarSymbol = @"$";
price = [[uPaidTxtFld.text substringFromIndex:1] floatValue];
result= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%.02f",dollarSymbol, price+0.05];
[uPaidTxtFld setText:result];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:result forKey:@"price"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason your code "is not adding" is that it tries to parse a number with a dollar sign in it. Since numbers are not supposed to contain dollar signs (they should be composed of digits and optional decimal separators) the failed parsing attempt produces a zero. After that, your code adds `0.05` to it, so you get the result that you described.

Now let's consider ways to fix the problem. First, you should separate formatting from keeping the current value. Make a numeric variable that stores the current amount in `NSUserDefaults`. Add `0.05` to that variable, and then format it as currency. Do not add the dollar sign manually - let iOS do it for you:

```
NSInteger amountPaid = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"price"];
amountPaid += 5; // amountPaid is in cents
NSDecimalNumber *amount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:amountPaid exponent:-2 isNegative:NO];
NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[uPaidTxtFld setText:[currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:amount]];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:result forKey:@"price"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

The idea is to store `amountPaid` as an integer, and convert it to a number only for formatting. It is a good idea to stay away from `float` and `double` values when your computations deals with money, because floating point representations do not provide proper precision even at reasonably coarse granularity (for example, adding together 100 of `0.01`s does not produce `1`, as it would in math).

Answer (score 0):

you just simply do it

```
result=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.02f",price+0.05];
```

Comment: Mind explaining? This was flagged by someone for deletion.